# Unresolved external symbol in qt project

Tags: c++, qt, unresolved-external

Okay so spend 30 min or so having a look at common causes for this issue and I can't see what is wrong.

The error I am getting is unresolved external symbol. The symbol in question being a class called AdventureDocs. The header is as follows.

```
#ifndef ADVENTUREDOCS_H
#define ADVENTUREDOCS_H

#include <QWidget>

class AdventureDocs : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    AdventureDocs(QObject *parent);
};

#endif // ADVENTUREDOCS_H
```

and the cpp

```
#include "adventuredocs.h"
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QTabWidget>

AdventureDocs::AdventureDocs(QObject *parent): QWidget(parent)
{
    QHBoxLayout *hLayout = 0;
    QVBoxLayout *vLayout = 0;
    QPushButton *button = 0;
    QLabel *label = 0;

    hLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    Q_ASSERT(hLayout);

    vLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    Q_ASSERT(vLayout);

    // Set the layout to the widget
    setLayout(hLayout);
    hLayout->addLayout(vLayout);

    // Draw widgets on main page.
    label = new QLabel(hLayout);
    Q_ASSERT(label);
    hLayout->addWidget(label);

    label->setText("Adventure Docs");
}
```

This is a class not a library or anything smart like that I used add new class in qt creator to add it and that added the header and cpp into the project file as follows.

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2016-06-12T11:06:47
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = AdventureDocs
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    adventuredocs.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    adventuredocs.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

finally in the mainwindow .cpp where i create an AdventureDocs object is where i get the error.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include "adventuredocs.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    AdventureDocs *main = 0;

    main =  new AdventureDocs(this);
    if (main != 0)
    {
        setCentralWidget(main);
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Can someone point out the bleeding obvious which I am clearly missing thanks.

Comment: And which error exactly do you get?

Comment: It was an unresolved external symbol error but I have sorted it out now. Like i said it was bleeding obvious I had not re-ran qmake since adding the file.

Answer (score 0):

sorted it out now. was me being silly and no re-running qmake